# SQL Server: Calculate Four Weeks From a Month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a simple solution to get 4 weeks for a month based on current date (each week starting from Monday - Friday).

For each week I need to update a table that already has current date and place a counter from Week 1 - 4 and continue to the following month starting from Week 6 - 8. and start from the beginning after week 8.

The query below is returning week number but for 7 days:

can I use something similar just for 5 days?

```
 DECLARE  @MyDate DATETIME  = '2020-08-03'
 --This assumes the weeks starts from Monday - Sunday
 DECLARE  @WeekNumber INTEGER = (DATEPART(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @MyDate)/7 * 7)/7 +1) 
 SELECT @WeekNumber
```

Comment: Some months will have more than 4 weeks?

Comment: Yes, but this will only run from Monday to Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer was not useful so I got rid of it.  This should do what you're looking for

```
declare @date datetime= '2020-08-03';

select dateadd(d, -4, dt.dt) start_dt,
       dt.dt end_dt,
       row_number() over (order by v.n) n
from
  (select datefromparts(year(@date),month(@date),1) first_dt) fd
 cross apply
  (select datediff(week, 0, fd.first_dt) wk_diff) wd
 cross apply
  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) v(n)
 cross apply
  (select dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday,  fd.first_dt) + 1 + @@datefirst) % 7), fd.first_dt) calc_dt) calc_dt
 cross apply
 (select dateadd(d, (v.n-1)*7, calc_dt) dt) dt
where
  dt.dt>=fd.first_dt;
```

Results

```
start_dt    end_dt      n
2020-08-03  2020-08-07  1
2020-08-10  2020-08-14  2
2020-08-17  2020-08-21  3
2020-08-24  2020-08-28  4
2020-08-31  2020-09-04  5
```